# Two sliders that interact in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I want to have two sliders that interact - when I change one, it changes the other immediately. Now simply using events like "OnValueChanged" is problematic, because it will could create an infinite loop ("OnValueChanged" doesn't actually check whether the new value is different, it just registers any sort of assignment of value).

So what are some good options to get this desired behavior - i.e. I when I change one slider, it also changes the other slider, but those changes don't actually call any events? Some of my ideas are:

1, I just check if there's any actual difference from the previous value. This should solve things. This should be fine, but I'm still sort of afraid of some feedback loop, especially if there's some conversion of types or something between sliders.

2, For a while I turn off the other sliders. This would seem like the most reasonable, safe option, but I'm not really sure how exactly to do this. I don't know how unity checks for changes in the first place. So I'm sort of unsure for "how long" to turn off the other sliders.

3, Similar to the above, but a very hacky, safe solution, is to keep some sort of Boolean value `bool` in each slider. If a slider changes, and it's about to change values of other sliders, I first set `bool` to false in all of these. When the "onValueChanged" is called on the other sliders, it checks for `bool` value and since it's false, it doesn't actually do anything, except for changing `bool` back to true. Basically I turn the slider off for one change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Slider.SetValueWithoutNotify()
```

Is your friend.

From Unity Script documentation:

> Set the value of the slider without invoking onValueChanged callback.

[Slider. SetValueWithoutNotify()](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.SetValueWithoutNotify.html)